# No terminal, no console

Tags: command-line

I installed ubuntu22.04 in virtualbox. cannot get a terminal, activities shows a rotating wheel for some seconds, then disappears- nothing else happens.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your VM? CPU count, RAM size, VRAM size etc. Did you check your ISO file, was it fully working during Live USB?

Comment: Have you saved a snapshot of your Ubuntu 22.04 guest OS in VirtualBox that you can restore back to?